# PHP - Start a cron job manually / let the server works instead of the user

Tags: php, cron, jobs

I have a quite slow script that need to be executed frequently (about 30 times in a minute) so the user can't execute it and the cron job runs at most every minute.

So, is there a way (using PHP) to let the server works instead of the user?

Comment: What does *"let the server works"* mean?

Comment: PHP and let the server works? Guess you forgot PHP only runs on the server...

Comment: 30 times a minute? Sounds like you need to write it as a daemon instead of a cron job.

Comment: You should consider rewrite the script.

Comment: I need to reduce the loading time of a page that has to load a thousand files to make a ranking

Answer (score 2):

This is quite easy: Use a flag file

Script running without user interaction (may be started by cron or shell, including PHP shell execute):

```
<?php
while (true) {
  while (file_exists('/path/to/flagfile')) sleep(1); //Can even use microsleep
  include ('/path/to/worker/script');
  touch('/path/to/flagfile');
}
?>
```

Script to trigger it (started from webserver via user interaction)

```
<?php
@unlink('/path/to/flagfile');
echo "Processing triggered!";
?>
```

Comment: The idea is alright, but consider that you might have file permission issues regarding users. The web (apache/httpd) user will be different than the cron. If configured properly, no problem.

Comment: Good script but, is there a way to do it without using the time? (cron executed on page load, not every second)

Comment: @Megadv The only thing the timer loop does, is to sleep most of the time! The page load will trigger the real execution. There is no real penalty on reducing this to 1/10 of a second, which is quite "immediately" with the page load.

Comment: @Anyone The only thing we need is a file, that can be written by the starting script and deleted by the webserver. Since you could just as well start the script from the webserver, this doesn't seem very hard.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to have a script like that being started from a web interface. This due to the page would never stop loading. A script like that should run from a command line, cron or daemon. What you could do is have a webscript start a background process which runs this script, but then you can get issues deleted the file manually doe to permission problems, hence I noted it as comment ;)

Comment: @Anyone: You can easily start a background process from a script and the page will stop loading!

Comment: I need to reduce the loading time of a script that has to load a thousand files to make a ranking. Is it a good idea to use a daemon?And how should i use it using PHP?

Comment: @Megadv Using a daemon will not reduce the time load the page, but it will 1. make sure, it is run only once and 2. will make it easier for you to create a "processing - please wait" structure

Comment: The user has to load just a file (an advertise) and then I have to make a ranking to choose another advertise to show. Make a ranking is a slow process and I need to use something like a cron job, but only when I need it. What can I do?

Comment: There is no such thing as a free lunch: If Ranking for a new ad takes N seconds, you can't serve more than 1/N requests/second (excluding parallelization). You should rethink your algorithm - if it costs you loading thousands of files per ad request, you will not make a competitive ad service.